# Can't get CSS working in Grafana on Mac OS X

Tags: gruntjs, npm, osx-yosemite, grafana

Following the instructions found here http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/ I am able to build Grafana and start the server listening on http://localhost:3000 but the CSS is obviously not working. I have attempted to re-execute the build commands for **Build the Front-end Assets** but I'm running into errors with the following sequence:

```
npm install
npm install -g grunt-cli
grunt
```

It isn't clear from which directory these commands should be executed. I am assuming $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana but when I execute the first command `npm install` I get a whole series of errors that look like this:

```
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/sam/.npm/_locks/glob-386d0e7784ce4d2e.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /Users/sam/.npm/_locks/glob-386d0e7784ce4d2e.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/sam/.npm/_locks/glob-386d0e7784ce4d2e.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/sam/.npm/_locks/glob-386d0e7784ce4d2e.lock' }
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /Users/sam/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/node_modules/glob, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I installed NodeJS from here https://nodejs.org/download/docs/latest/ and I have checked /usr/local/bin for npm and it exists but I'm not sure if I missed a configuration step when installing it.

When I move to the next step of executing `npm install -g grunt-cli` I get a single error block (similar to the previous) as follows:

```
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/sam/.npm/_locks/grunt-cli-58f484dab06f0a30.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /Users/sam/.npm/_locks/grunt-cli-58f484dab06f0a30.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/sam/.npm/_locks/grunt-cli-58f484dab06f0a30.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/sam/.npm/_locks/grunt-cli-58f484dab06f0a30.lock' }
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sam/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/npm-debug.log
```

Finally when I execute `grunt` I get the following fatal error:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

I have also verified that I have the package.json and Gruntfile.js files in the project directory. The following is a list of all the files if helps:

```
09:25:54|~/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana$ ls -alF
total 47648
drwxr-xr-x  42 sam  staff      1428 Sep  5 21:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x   3 sam  staff       102 Sep  5 17:59 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff        36 Sep  5 18:02 .bowerrc
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       344 Sep  5 18:02 .bra.toml
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       197 Sep  5 18:02 .editorconfig
drwxr-xr-x  13 sam  staff       442 Sep  5 19:28 .git/
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       345 Sep  5 18:02 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x   3 sam  staff       102 Sep  5 18:02 .hooks/
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       418 Sep  5 18:02 .jscs.json
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       287 Sep  5 18:02 .jsfmtrc
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       564 Sep  5 18:02 .jshintrc
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff     54566 Sep  5 18:02 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       571 Sep  5 18:02 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x   5 sam  staff       170 Sep  5 18:02 Godeps/
-rw-r--r--@  1 sam  staff      1289 Sep  5 18:02 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       578 Sep  5 18:02 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       638 Sep  5 18:02 NOTICE.md
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff      5286 Sep  5 18:02 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       591 Sep  5 18:02 appveyor.yml
drwxr-xr-x   3 sam  staff       102 Sep  5 18:02 benchmarks/
drwxr-xr-x   4 sam  staff       136 Sep  5 19:28 bin/
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       569 Sep  5 18:02 bower.json
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff     11721 Sep  5 18:02 build.go
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff       637 Sep  5 18:02 circle.yml
drwxr-xr-x   5 sam  staff       170 Sep  5 18:02 conf/
drwxr-xr-x   5 sam  staff       170 Sep  5 18:50 data/
drwxr-xr-x   8 sam  staff       272 Sep  5 18:02 docker/
drwxr-xr-x   9 sam  staff       306 Sep  5 18:02 docs/
drwxr-xr-x   8 sam  staff       272 Sep  5 18:02 emails/
-rw-r--r--@  1 sam  staff     35472 Sep  5 19:46 err.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 sam  staff  24195460 Sep  5 18:49 grafana*
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff        24 Sep  5 18:02 latest.json
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff      2857 Sep  5 18:02 main.go
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff      6693 Sep  5 21:21 npm-debug.log
-rw-r--r--@  1 sam  staff      1870 Sep  5 18:02 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   4 sam  staff       136 Sep  5 18:02 packaging/
drwxr-xr-x  17 sam  staff       578 Sep  5 18:02 pkg/
drwxr-xr-x  12 sam  staff       408 Sep  5 18:02 public/
drwxr-xr-x   7 sam  staff       238 Sep  5 18:02 tasks/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 sam  staff      1178 Sep  5 18:02 test.sh*
drwxr-xr-x   3 sam  staff       102 Sep  5 18:02 tests/
drwxr-xr-x   3 sam  staff       102 Sep  5 18:02 vendor/
```

When I start the server with `./bin/grafana-server` (from $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana) I get the expected output but then navigate to http://localhost:3000 and the last line with the 404 error is added as follows:

```
09:27:13|~/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana$ ./bin/grafana-server 
2015/09/05 21:34:22 [I] Starting Grafana
2015/09/05 21:34:22 [I] Version: 2.2.0-pre1, Commit: v2.1.2+199-gf27f028, Build date: 2015-09-04 08:34:01 -0700 MST
2015/09/05 21:34:22 [I] Configuration Info
Config files:
  [0]: /Users/sam/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/conf/defaults.ini
Paths:
  home: /Users/sam/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana
  data: /Users/sam/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/data
  logs: /Users/sam/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/data/log

2015/09/05 21:34:22 [I] Database: sqlite3
2015/09/05 21:34:22 [I] Migrator: Starting DB migration
2015/09/05 21:34:22 [I] Listen: http://0.0.0.0:3000
2015/09/05 21:36:33 [I] Completed /css/grafana.dark.min.css 404 Not Found in 1.799267ms
```

The following is the contents of Gruntfile.js which was included in the project (i.e. I didn't write it):

```
/* jshint node:true */
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var os = require('os');
  var config = {
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    baseDir: '.',
    srcDir: 'public',
    destDir: 'dist',
    tempDir: 'tmp',
    arch: os.arch(),
    platform: process.platform.replace('win32', 'windows'),
  };

  if (process.platform.match(/^win/)) {
    config.arch = process.env.hasOwnProperty('ProgramFiles(x86)') ? 'x64' : 'x86';
  }

  config.pkg.version = grunt.option('pkgVer') || config.pkg.version;

  // load plugins
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // load task definitions
  grunt.loadTasks('tasks');

  // Utility function to load plugin settings into config
  function loadConfig(config,path) {
    require('glob').sync('*', {cwd: path}).forEach(function(option) {
      var key = option.replace(/\.js$/,'');
      // If key already exists, extend it. It is your responsibility to avoid naming collisions
      config[key] = config[key] || {};
      grunt.util._.extend(config[key], require(path + option)(config,grunt));
    });
    // technically not required
    return config;
  }

  // Merge that object with what with whatever we have here
  loadConfig(config,'./tasks/options/');
  // pass the config to grunt
  grunt.initConfig(config);
};
```

Also since it was asked for, here is a list of all the CSS files in the project (though I'm not sure exactly if these are the CSS files used by the UI):

```
10:23:03|~/Projects/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana$ find . -iname "*.css"
./emails/assets/css/ink.css
./emails/assets/css/style.css
./public/vendor/angular/angular-csp.css
./public/vendor/angular-native-dragdrop/demo/css/styles.css
./public/vendor/angular-native-dragdrop/docs/css/styles.css
./public/vendor/css/font-awesome.min.css
./public/vendor/css/normalize.min.css
./public/vendor/css/spectrum.css
./public/vendor/css/timepicker.css
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get the CSS working correctly? I expect that I am missing something obvious but I've been at this for a few hours now and can't find anything that helps. Thanks!

Comment: can you show the gruntfile you are running? about the css you are probably not setting the src path correctly.  can you show where is this css  in the project?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the contents of the Gruntfile.js. I am not sure about where the CSS is located since this isn't my project (searching for it now).

Comment: Just added list of CSS files in project. Please let me know if any other supporting info would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You maybe are missing the path when import the css.

possible just adding 'public/vendor' to the path will solve this issue.

about the grunt file, it looks like the node are loading the task inside another folde:

```
 loadConfig(config,'./tasks/options/');      

 so I think you should update the question or look up the tasks at this line
```

you can see the file example of grunt [url](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)

look what the grunt does with default task (e.g: $ grunt)

Comment: I'm not sure where the CSS path is located for the Grafana. I would expect it to be correctly configured so that all I need to do is down and build. I suspect I either did something wrong in the build process or the build instructions are incomplete. I am hoping that someone who has built Grafana on Mac OS X can point out my mistake.